# MySQL combine counts on columns from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to combine these two queries into one where table1.column1 = table2.column1 so that it would return the following?

```
select column1, count(column1) as var1 from table1 where  datediff(now(),createdAt) = 0 group by column1

select column1, count(column1) as var2 from table2 where  datediff(now(),createdAt) = 0 group by column1

column1, var1, var2
column1, var1, var2
column1, var1, var2
column1, var1, var2
```

Comment: Have you tried subqueries and `join`?

Comment: I attempted but couldn't get the syntax correct and the same with union

Comment: select t1.column1, t1.var1, t2.var2
(select column1, count(column1) as var1 from table1 where  datediff(now(),createdAt) = 0 group by column1) t1,
(select column1, count(column1) as var2 from table2 where  datediff(now(),createdAt) = 0 group by column1) t2
where 
t1.column1= t2.column1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquerys and INNER JOIN

```
SELECT 
    a.column1, a.var1, b.vae2
FROM
    (SELECT 
        column1, COUNT(column1) AS var1
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(NOW(), createdAt) = 0
    GROUP BY column1) a
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        column1, COUNT(column1) AS var2
    FROM
        table2
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(NOW(), createdAt) = 0
    GROUP BY column1) b ON a.column1 = b.column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select column1, count(column1) as var1 from table1 where  datediff(now(),createdAt) = 0 group by column1
) a 
JOIN (
    select column1, count(column1) as var2 from table2 where  datediff(now(),createdAt) = 0 group by column1
) b ON b.column1 = a.column1
```